# How flexible may my directory structure be when automatically harvesting files for a WIX installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

Forgive me for my ignorance -- I've been doing some reading, but not quite ready to try anything out yet.

Currently, we have a .wxs file which is not able to be maintained easily. All of the files are manually added/removed whenever a new file is comitted/removed from SVN. We constantly have broken install builds due to the ball being dropped between creation of a new file and updating of the .wxs install file.

As such, I would like to automatically harvest the files in the solution. [HOW TO CONSUME MSDEPLOY STAGED WEB SITE OUTPUT IN A WIX INSTALLER](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-consume-msdeploy-staged-web-site-output-in-a.aspx) seems to outline what I want to do, but it doesn't address one of my main concerns. That is -- does harvesting files like this allow for customization of the directory structure, or will the installer now install files in locations mimicing our solution?

I am struggling to make the logical leap from "automatically detect new files and folders" to "know where to put new files automatically." Is there a way to set up some pre-defined actions saying something like "All files and folders under this parent folder should be installed to [other defined directory]"

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using WiX on an ASP.net probject do dynamically include all of the website files and database scripts that get run during installation.

I extract the files from the solution using a heat task like so

```
  <HeatDirectory
                  ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
                  Directory="$(WebRoot)"
                  GenerateGuidsNow="yes"
                  ComponentGroupName="MasterPlanWeb"
                  OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Setup\Product\Fragments\wwwfiles.wxs"
                  SuppressFragments="yes"
                  DirectoryRefId="WEBROOT"
                  KeepEmptyDirectories="yes"
                  PreprocessorVariable="var.WebRoot"
                  SuppressRegistry="yes"
                  SuppressRootDirectory="yes"
                  SuppressCom="yes" />
```

and then in my main wix script those get referenced as

```
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="MasterPlan">
        <Directory Id="WEBROOT" Name="wwwroot" />
        <Directory Id="DATABASESRC" Name="databasesrc" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

The link between these two parts if the DirectoryRefId in the first xml chunk and the Directory Id in the second one.

So basically the solution structure directly under my HEATed directory is copied as is however I am able to change the root.

For instance if I run HEAT over c:\mywebsite and that directory contains

- \people\
- \accounts\
- \scripts\

those subdirectories will be included.

The second part allows me to set the root directory during installation, so if the user choose c:\test as the directory to install to the following directories would be created (with their heated content)

- c:\test\people\
- c:\test\accounts\
- c:\test\scripts\

If you really wanted the subdirectories to have all their data put under the root for instance you might be able to do a loop over every folder and run the same command specifying the same DirectoryRefId for them all.

Comment: +1 for showing off the HeatDirectory Task.  All the other questions I have read thus far only talk about running heat.exe as a pre-build task.