# Automatically keeping WiX installer updated with newly created files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

I have a web application solution existing under Visual Studio 2010. Part of this solution is a WiX Project responsible for generating a .msi installer.

I was reading through the WiX tutorial in an attempt to learn how to automatically harvest files when I encountered the following:

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/components-of-a-different-color

> A tool in WiX, Heat serves to harvest data from various sources (folders, files, DLLs, ActiveX controls, performance counters, web sites) where the number of entries might be too large to author the corresponding WiX source file manually. Its primary intention is to be run once, to collect the data to be used later in the usual maintenance of the source files, not to be part of a build environment where it is run on a changing set of input data over and over again. If you still want to use it in this second way, you have to be very careful to make sure that changes in the input don't introduce unwelcome effects (mostly breaking the component rules). Heat does have features that help you achieve this goal but be careful when using them.

It seems like I would like to not use its primary function, but the tutorial only teases me with hints about how to do what I would like to accomplish.

Is it really a poor idea to try and automatically maintain the files installed by a WiX installation? I'm tired of broken builds where someone has comitted a new file, but forgotten to update the WiX installers with a reference to that new file.

How are others handling this situation?

Thanks.

Re: teasing -- The tutorial states that 'Heat does have features that help you achieve this goal' but I can't find what features are being referenced. After harvesting a project -- what's next? Does heat become responsible for creating the .wxs file I will eventually use -- or am I supposed to just consume this list of files and build a more ful-featured .wxs file after the fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using [Heat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Tallow.2FHeat) in my ASP.NET web application to automatically harvest all of the files for the application.

It works quite well. One thing is that each time it runs it generates a new ID for the files, and I believe this makes things a bit harder when doing upgrades. You would probably need to do an uninstall and then an install to get the newer files.

It has been a while since I looked into it and that could have changed though.

Comment: The .wxs file we currently use has a lot more in it than just references to files. Yet, heat generates a .wxs file. Am I supposed to consume one .wxs file and generate another wxs file using it? The installation structure doesn't mimic the structure of files in the project -- we define the 'source' property for every file. I understand that I can customize a little bit of where files are going by passing cmd line parameters to heat -- but this doesn't seem like its enough. I have heat harvesting a project -- but the .wxs file I'm left with is nowhere near as fully-featured as our current .wxs.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8598296/351614 . The output generated by heat will only be for the files your require you still need other wxs files for the various metadata about your installer. Think of the output of heat as a class that your main Proudct.wxs references and the content of the heat file can change. In terms of the directory structure if you have specific requirements you would probalby have to get your msbuild/cmd-fu on and script it out in such a way that it generates the directory structure you want.

Comment: this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/asp_wix.aspx may give you a better idea of how it works and all falls together

Comment: That codeproject example was just what I was looking for! Awesome.

Answer (score 5):

There's a tool called [Paraffin](https://github.com/Wintellect/Paraffin) that fixes some of the shortcomings of *Heat*. It can, in particular, update file lists. Also see [this Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wx-users/8HBWT1wz3a4/TYWtf3QPX-QJ) for a discussion of this.